# How to show/hide divs based on radio button value?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with six radio buttons blocks.

When user select `option no for 3 or more times`, I have to show the `Text 1` or `Text 2` divs on entering the submit button.

Below is my code,

```
<form>
    <fieldset>  
    <div class="input-radio">  
      <input type="radio" value="yes" name="somename"/>  
      <input type="radio" value="no" name="somename"/>  
    </div>
    <!-- 6 identical blocks -->
    </fieldset>

    <div class="submit">
      <span>Submit</span>
    </div>      

    <div class="text-1">
    Text 1
    </div> 
    <div class="text-2">
      Text 2
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please provide clearer question

Comment: The question is not clear. Please explain properly and show what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" value="yes" class="chkbx" name="somename"/>  
<input type="radio" value="no" class="chkbx" name="somename"/> 
<input type="radio" value="yes" class="chkbx" name="somename1"/>  
<input type="radio" value="no" class="chkbx" name="somename1"/> 
<input type="radio" value="yes" class="chkbx" name="somename2"/>  
<input type="radio" value="no" class="chkbx" name="somename2"/> 
<input type="button" id="button"  />
```

Javascript:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#button").on("click", function(){
            if($("input.chkbx:checked[value='no']").length == 3)
                $("#button").text("text1");
            else
                $("#button").text("text2");
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Yea it works but I did some alterations to suit the question kindly check https://jsfiddle.net/fx5bsbdw/

Comment: Great...!! I assumed the HTML part and did accordingly..!!